# Accordion in Flex with only headers and no containers

Tags: apache-flex, actionscript-3, accordion

Is it possible to create Accordion with only the headers without adding any containers in it? Is there a way so that I can just create the Accordion with three sections with only labels?

Comment: Say more about your intended use, I suspect the Accordion is not necessarily the right choice.

Answer (score 0):

The children of an Accordian must be containers.  IF the accordian doesn't expand/collapse to reveal/hide content, it's not much of an accordian.

If you're just looking for the visual appearance of a closed Accordian, why not use a list with a styled itemRenderer?

Answer (score 0):

Make "fake" Containers.

- create containers for each accordion header
- give the label-only containers a height of 0 and alpha to 0
- containers that should be opened give height > 0
- set resizeToContent in accordion to true
- set verticalGap of accordion to 0

That should do the trick.